# Stateless Widget not displaying Provider data unless I pop screen and reload

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateless widget that displays a list of ListTiles.
It gets the data from a provider and sets it as final.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/inspections.dart';
import '../widgets/inspection_list_tile.dart';

class ExistingInspectionsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<Inspections>(context, listen: false).fetchAndSetInspections();
    final inspections =
        Provider.of<Inspections>(context, listen: false).inspections;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Previous Inspections'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: inspections.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InspectionListTile(
                inspection: inspections[index],
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sections_list_screen',
                      arguments: {'report': inspections[index]});
                },
              );
            }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          return Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/create_inspection_screen');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I load this screen and the list is empty but if I pop the screen and reload the list is there.
How can I get the data to display on the first load of the screen.  I though the fetchAndSetInspections being an async method in the provider would cause the app to wait for the data to be retrieved from the sqlite database.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/inspection.dart';
import '../helpers/inspection_db_helper.dart';

class Inspections with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Inspection> _inspections = [];

  List<Inspection> get inspections {
    return [..._inspections];
  }

  Future<void> fetchAndSetInspections() async {
    final InspectionDBHelper inspectionDBHelper = InspectionDBHelper();
    _inspections = await inspectionDBHelper.getInspections();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This seems to catch me out a lot and I don't seem to be able to grasp whats happening.

Please help.

Comment: If you want to rely on data returned by an async method, use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). If you are using `Provider`, why don't you listen to changes? You are explicitly disabling listening in the above example.

Comment: I have taken your advice and used a FutureBuilder. It has fixed my issue and reduced my lines of code.

Comment: Glad to have helped! ;)